# How to use 'event-more-text' prop in vuetify v-calendar

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using v-calendar in vuetify v.2.4.2. The [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#event-more-text) say that prop 'event-more-text' *is the text to display in the more ‘button’ given the number of hidden events* (defaults to string '$vuetify.calendar.moreEvents'). If, say, 3 events are hidden in 'month' view, the rendered text is **3 more** by default. If I set prop 'event-more-text' to string 'events hidden' the rendered text is **events hidden** without the leading number (3). How can I change the default behavior so that text **3 events hidden** is rendered instead? How can I get the number of hidden events for the specific date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had the same problem and solved it by looking at [their code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/locale/en.ts).
So for you it should be:

`<v-calendar event-more-text="{0} events hidden" />`